# Symfony Apache Fatal error: Call to undefined function pg_connect()

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony

when i am trying to connect with my php application, to my remote database server which has PostgreSQL installed in it, this error appears to me:

**CRITICAL - Fatal Error: Call to undefined function xxx/xxx/xxx/file.php**

My application running use symfony2 framework, with php -v 5.6 .

I suppose that some libraries is not setting on my file php.ini, but i try to follow any suggest about this error, such a upgrade brew or similar command.

Someone could help me, please?

Comment: Your server does not have postgresql php extension installed. Or your webserver is not configured to use it.

Comment: Thx, but could you suggest me how can i configured it on my apache webserver or where setting a postgresql extension?

Comment: Just google for any article on how to configure php and apache